# Uncaught DivisionByZeroError: Division by zero Error in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to do an Calculation of my Project
were I need to do Division and Multiplication to get my Ans
but getting an error "Uncaught DivisionByZeroError: Division by zero".
my Code and Error as shown in Screenshots

```
        $total_plates=$row['s_tps'];
    $total_a_kg=$row['s_kg'];
    $plates_per_kg=$row['s_pkg'];
    $remaing_kg=(1000/$plates_per_kg)*$total_plates;
    echo "$remaing_kg";
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBPxG.png]

Comment: check for the value of **$plates_per_kg**

Comment: And check whether `$row` actually has a value for `s_pkg`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following line,

`$remaing_kg=(1000/$plates_per_kg)*$total_plates;`

if '$plates_per_kg' value is 0, then this error will occur

Or "0", or null, or false, or array() or anything that intval would return 0 for.

Edit: Thanks for the comment @msbit

Comment: Or `"0"`, or `null`, or `false`, or anything* that [`intval`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) would return 0 for - *mostly, `array()` for example fails with `Unsupported operand type`

Comment: Thank you . Problem has been solved I found mistake of 0 in my database column in my one of the column row value of  $plates_per_kg is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Code is okay

```
        $total_plates=$row['s_tps'];
    $total_a_kg=$row['s_kg'];
    $plates_per_kg=$row['s_pkg'];
    $pkg=1000;
    $remaing_kg=($pkg/$plates_per_kg)*$total_plates;
```

Their is problem in your database find out target column of $plates_per_kg and see that any row contain 0 if you find 0 in any row then this error will occur so remove that zero. or while you creating DB set an restriction to not take 0.
Thank You.